# ROS 2 Humble Hawksbill package not found

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed official guide on this [link](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) but apt cannot find Humble Hawksbill required packages.

The repository link on ros2.list is

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal main
```

that seems correct, and the previous version was correctly installed.

Wasn't it released in May?

Even the method to build it from source on same link requires packages that aren't available on ubuntu universe and provided repository e.g. , `python3-flake8-blind-except`. Latest time that I have installed ROS building the sources was with ROS 1 Noetic, I haven't tried the previous method since the build procedure seems changed and I have preferred ask here before further attempts.

(Also, what about using a decent build automation tool to have consistent built packages release with various platforms especially Debian, OpenWRT and arm64 CPUs that are very popular for SBC based robots?)

OS: Kubuntu Focal Fossa 64 bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402163/ros-2-humble-hawksbill-package-not-found/) by [SMH17](https://answers.ros.org/users/107936/smh17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot install Humble on (K)Ubuntu Focal. Humble only gets binary packages (ie: `.deb`s) on Ubuntu Jammy.

This is stated on the page you linked:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SMH17](https://answers.ros.org/users/107936/smh17/) on 2022-06-10**:
Ok, thanks. I haven't paid much attention to "Jammy" because I wouldn't have expected a so limited distribution on release, assuming that at least it was available for most widespread release of Ubuntu family, considering that has been released only for Ubuntu, and 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish release is very recent.

**Comment by [Rick_O](https://answers.ros.org/users/112559/rick_o/) on 2022-08-02**:
This is a bit confusing. Here : [link text](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html) is stated as an alternative to build from source for the Tier 3: Ubuntu Linux - Focal (20.04) 64-bit.
If this is not possible, then the Ubuntu(Source) alternative is misleading.
Please correct me if I am wrong.